# How to write ods latex template in SAS

Tags: sas, latex, ods

Based on this document:

https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings14/2033-2014.pdf

I created the attached result and using the attached code,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZImB.png)

but I want to produce my own template that creates output as this (tables with multi-rows and partial grids):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOd3W.png)

Does anyone know how to achieve this? Or a good source to learn writing the language used in ods template. Much thanks!

```
ods path(prepend) work.templat(update);

proc template;
 define tagset Tagsets.event1;
 define event colspec_entry;
 put just "|" /if ^cmp( just, "d");
 put "r|" /if cmp( just, "d");
 end;
 define event table;
 start:
 put NL;
 put NL;
 put "\begin{longtable}";
 finish:
 put "\hline \end{longtable}" NL;
 put NL;
 end;
 define event stacked_cell;
 start:
 put NL;
 put "\begin{tabular}";
 trigger alignment;
 finish:
 put "\end{tabular}" NL;
 end;
 define event colspecs;
 start:
 put "{";
 finish:
 put "}\hline" NL;
 end;
 define event colspec_entry;
 put just /if ^cmp( just, "d");
 put "r" /if cmp( just, "d");
 end;
 define event row;
 finish:
 put "\\" NL;
 end;
 define event header;
 start:
 trigger data;
 finish:
 trigger data;
 end;
 define event data;
 start:
 put VALUE /if cmp( $sascaption, "true");
 break /if cmp( $sascaption, "true");
 put %nrstr(" & ") /if ^cmp( COLSTART, "1");
 put " ";
 unset $colspan;
 set $colspan colspan;
 do /if exists( $colspan) | exists ( $cell_align );
 put "\multicolumn{";
 put colspan /if $colspan;
 put "1" /if ^$colspan;
 put "}{";
 put "|" /if ^$instacked;
 put just;
 put "|" /if ^$instacked;
 put "}{";
 done;
 put tranwrd(VALUE,"-","$-$") /if contains( HTMLCLASS, "data");
  put VALUE /if ^contains( HTMLCLASS, "data");
 finish:
 break /if cmp( $sascaption, "true");
 put "}" /if exists( $colspan) | exists ( $cell_align );
 end;
 define event rowspanfillsep;
 put %nrstr(" & ");
 end;
 define event rowspancolspanfill;
 put " ~";
 end;
 define event image;
 put "\includegraphics{";
 put BASENAME /if ^exists( NOBASE);
 put URL;
 put "}" NL;
 end;
 parent = tagsets.latex;
 end;
run;

data t;
length v1 $20;
input v1 $ v2;
datalines;
f=ma 21
sqrt(abd) 22
;
run;

ods tagsets.simplelatex file="/scratch/columbia/zz89/t1.tex";
proc print data=t;
run;
ods tagsets.simplelatex close;

ods tagsets.event1 file="/scratch/columbia/zz89/t2.tex";
proc print data=t;
run;
ods tagsets.event1 close;

data re1;
 infile "/scratch/columbia/zz89/t1.tex" pad missover;
 file "/scratch/columbia/zz89/t1_out.tex";
 length c1 $200;
 input c1 $ 1-200;
 p1=index(c1,'sqrt');
 if p1>0 then do;
 c2=substr(c1,(p1+5));
p2=index(c2,')');
 c3=substr(c1,1,(p1-1))||'$\sqrt{'||scan(c2,1,')') ||'}$'||substr(c2,(p2+1));
 put c3;
 end;
 else put c1;
run;
```

Comment: Writing a tagset can be an **od**iou**s** endeavor, and is not a common practice.   The desired output has the look of something achievable with `Proc REPORT` -- can you add some actual data to the question.  See documentation for “DEFINE TAGSET Statement” at http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/odsug/61723/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002566872.htm

Comment: @Richard Here's some

`data fakedata;
  length Type $6  Cat $4;
  infile datalines dlm=',' dsd;
  input Type $ Cat $ EWVAL XSVAL  ;
datalines;
Market,Low,-32.83,15.56 
Market,2,-3.36,4.82 
Market,3,12.48,4.51 
Market,4,31.22,6.81 
Market,High,97.89,61.57 
Micro,Low,-34.76,16 
Micro,2,-3.6, 4.81 
Micro,3,12.36,4.49 
Micro,4,31.29,6.81 
Micro,High,104.34,65.95 
Small,Low,-29.12,13.49 
Small,2,-3.22,4.84 
Small,3,12.56,4.52 
Small,4,31.31,6.83 
Small,High,91.9, 53.43
Big,Low,-25.21,11.15 
Big,2,-2.9,4.77 
Big,3,12.6,4.5 
Big,4,30.93,6.74 
Big,High,80.46,41.73
;
run;`